# How to query value using get_json_object()

Tags: json, pyspark, hive

I need to extract the value of attribute where the namespace is GLOBALID in the following json format, e.g in this example I need to extract "123456"

```
[{
        "namespace": "GLOBALID",
        "key": "ID",
        "value": "123456"
    },
    {
        "namespace": "RPS",
        "key": "ID",
        "value": "12xt12"
    }
]
```

However when I use select `get_json_object(json_column, '$.GLOBALID.value')` it is not extracting the value (edited)

Answer (score 0):

For the pyspark, create dataframe and filter.

```py
json = [
    {
        "namespace": "GLOBALID",
        "key": "ID",
        "value": "123456"
    },
    {
        "namespace": "RPS",
        "key": "ID",
        "value": "12xt12"
    }
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(json)
df.show()

# +---+---------+------+
# |key|namespace| value|
# +---+---------+------+
# | ID| GLOBALID|123456|
# | ID|      RPS|12xt12|
# +---+---------+------+
```

```py
df.filter("namespace = 'GLOBALID'").select('value').rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
# ['123456']
```

Comment: I can't use python code or data frame in the tools that I use for ETL, only spark function are allowed

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the `json` string as a `JSON` value and then apply filtering. This is needed since Spark does not allow for filter expressions in `JSONPath`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField

df = spark.createDataFrame([('[{"namespace":"GLOBALID","key":"ID","value":"123456"},{"namespace":"RPS","key":"ID","value":"12xt12"}]', ), ], ("json_column", ))


json_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('namespace', StringType(),), \
                                    StructField('value', StringType(),)]))

df.select(F.explode(F.from_json("json_column", json_schema)).alias("json"))\
  .filter(F.col("json")["namespace"] == "GLOBALID")\
  .select("json.value")\
  .show()
```

### Output

```
+------+
| value|
+------+
|123456|
+------+
```

Comment: I can't use python code or data frame in the tools that I use for ETL, only spark function are allowed

Comment: `F.from_json` and `filter` are all spark functions. Do you mean to say you the JSON as a string as-is?